# D7Zip lista de arquivos

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou usando o D7Zip(https://code.google.com/p/d7zip/source/) para extrair arquivos, e gostaria de receber toda a list de arquivos do arquivo compactado. Na documentação, achei isso:

```
with CreateInArchive(CLSID_CFormat7z) do
 begin
   OpenFile('c:\test.7z');
   for i := 0 to NumberOfItems - 1 do
    if not ItemIsFolder[i] then
      Writeln(ItemPath[i]);
 end;
```

Que deixei assim:

```
with CreateInArchive(CLSID_CFormat7z) do
 begin
   OpenFile('c:\test.7z');
   for i := 0 to NumberOfItems - 1 do
    if not ItemIsFolder[i] then
      FilesInZ[i] := ItemPath[i];
 end;
```

Claro, antes declarei:

```
FilesInZ : array of string;
```

Ao executar, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Access Violation at address 004047B0 in module 'Launcher.exe'. Read of address 00000000.
```

O único erro que dá, é um warning:

```
[Warning] LauncherUnit.pas(120): Variable 'filesinz' might not have been initialized
```

A linha é essa:

```
 FilesInZ[i] := ItemPath[i];
```

Como poderia resolver?

Comment: Não sei, o erro da em tempo de execução

Comment: O único erro, é um warning. Editei o post.

Comment: Está tudo no post, o modo que declarei: FilesInZ : array of string;
E sei que é esse trecho pois quando tiro ele, não da o erro.

Comment: Não estou setando, não entendo muito de arrays no Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Delphi / Pascal, arrays dinâmicos são declarados sem uma quantidade de "espaços" para uso inicial

```
var 
  vetor: array of string;
```

Então, se você tentar adicionar valores a ele antes de adicionar esses "espaços" gerará um erro de violação de acesso.

É como declarar um array de tamanho definido e tentar acessar um item em uma posição que não existe.

```
var
  vetor: array[5] of string;
begin
  vetor[5] := 'Olá mundo!'; // <-- isso gera erro.
```

No exemplo, apesar de ter informado o vetor com cinco "espaços" de uso, você precisa saber que os vetores iniciam da posição zero. Logo, esse vetor teria apenas as seguintes posições:

```
vetor[0] := 'Olá mundo 1';
vetor[1] := 'Olá mundo 2';
vetor[2] := 'Olá mundo 3';
vetor[3] := 'Olá mundo 4';
vetor[4] := 'Olá mundo 5';
```

A posição máxima é a 4, `vetor[4]`. A menor é a 0, `vetor[0]`, claro.

No começo, para quem está aprendendo, isso pode ser um pouco confuso mas se acostuma com o tempo.

#### Mas e os vetores dinâmicos?

Como disse, os vetores dinâmicos iniciam sem espaços e para trabalhar com ele você tem duas condições:

1. Saber exatamente quantos espaço precisará;
2. Adicionar conforme necessário.

Na maioria dos casos, usa-se o array dinâmico quando não se sabe quantos espaços serão usados, e para isso implementa-se conforme necessário.

Para isso, precisa conhecer alguns recursos para se trabalhar com arrays no Delphi.

**Função Length()**: Usada para saber o tamanho atual do vetor

```
var
  vetor: array of string;          
  tamanho: integer;
begin
  tamanho := Length(vetor);  // <-- nesse momento o vetor possui 0 de tamanho, 
                             // ou seja, nenhum espaço para uso

  SetLength(vetor, Length(vetor) + 1);

  tamanho := Length(vetor); // <-- nesse momento o vetor possui 1 de tamanho,
                            // ou seja, 1 espaço para uso, índice 0 (zero) vetor[0].
```

**Função High()**: Usada para saber a maior posição do vetor

```
var
  vetor: array of string;
  max: integer;
begin
  max := High(vetor); // <-- nesse momento a maior posição do vetor é -1,
                      // ou seja, ainda não há posição, então retorna -1.

  SetLength(vetor, Length(vetor) + 1);

  max := High(vetor); // <-- nesse momento a maior posição do vetor é 0 (zero),
                      // ou seja, o vetor possui uma posição para uso, logo essa 
                      // posição é a 0 (zero)

  SetLength(vetor, Length(vetor) + 1);

  max := High(vetor); // <-- agora, a posição máxima é 1
```

**Função SetLength()**:  Usada para setar tamanho em vetores dinâmicos

Foi usada nos exemplos anteriores e descreverei aqui:

1. o primeiro parâmetro é o próprio vetor que deseja-se alterar o tamanho dele.
2. o segundo parâmetro é o tamanho que deseja-se setar para o vetor.

Logo, para sempre adicionar uma posição a mais no vetor você usa `Length()` para pegar o seu tamanho atual e então adicionar mais 1.

```
SetLength(vetor, Length(vetor) - 1);
```

Com a mesma função você pode remover todas as posições do vetor

```
SetLength(vetor, 0);
```

---

### Aos finalmentes

No seu caso, aconselharia fazer o seguinte:

```
with CreateInArchive(CLSID_CFormat7z) do
begin
  OpenFile('c:\test.7z');
  for i := 0 to NumberOfItems - 1 do
  begin
    if not ItemIsFolder[i] then
    begin
      SetLength(FilesInZ, Length(FilesInZ) + 1);
      FilesInZ[High(FilesInZ)] := ItemPath[i];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Perceba que adiciono uma posição: `SetLength(FilesInZ, Length(FilesInZ) + 1);`

Logo em seguida adiciono o valor na última posição que ele possui: `FilesInZ[High(FilesInZ)] := ItemPath[i];`
Usei o `High()` para pegar a última posição.